# Set MediaItem on ImageField

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

Currently `mediaItem.Src` is throwing an obsolete warning and states using the MediaItem property instead. The `mediaItem.MediaItem` has no setter though. Is this warning really just to get people to use something like:

```
var image = new Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem(imageField.MediaItem);
Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(image);
```

Is `.Src` (and related field properties) still the recommended way to actually set the field's value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you'd set the media ID instead of the media item property.

Answer (score 1):

I would refer to the Content API Cookbook ([PDF link](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/content_api_cookbook-usletter.pdf)) under section 4.1.7

Some sample code from it:

```
home.Editing.BeginEdit();
imageField.Clear();
imageField.Src = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(sampleMedia);
imageField.MediaID = sampleMedia.ID;
imageField.MediaPath = sampleMedia.MediaPath;
...
```

Comment: Mark, the Src and MediaPath properties are the ones that throw the obsolete warning.