# What properties replace obsoleted Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField properties?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

It is unclear to me from the compiler warning which fields I should be using in this code:

```
    Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField imgField = item.Fields[FieldName];
    if (imgField != null)
    {
        //Finally, save the actual values for our intended Image into the item
        imgField.Src = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(mediaItem);
        imgField.MediaID = mediaItem.ID;
        imgField.MediaPath = mediaItem.MediaPath;
        imgField.Alt = mediaItem.Alt;
    }
```

I get a compiler warning about imgField.Src and imgField.MediaPath.  The Src warning is 'Use MediaItem property' instead... which makes little sense, because those are entirely different property types.  The MediaPath warning says 'You can retrive[sic] Path from MediaItem."  Well... Again, this makes very little sense because what I'm actually doing here is setting the necessary properties for MediaItem.  It would be empty or NULL otherwise.  Should these four lines of code just be changed to imgField.MediaItem = mediaItem?  I am skeptical.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399980/set-mediaitem-on-imagefield

Comment: Submit to Sitecore support - best way to get the answer

Answer (score 2):

What it's trying to transition you away from doing is getting properties from the Imagefield and instead just getting the MediaItem that is referenced by the ImageField and then calling the properties that way..since it's the actual Sitecore item in the media library. Once you do that, you've got access to all the properties just like you would any other Sitecore item.